# How to delay a call to a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code which calls another function, i.e.:

```
$('input[name='f01']:checked').each(function() {
                                  setCBCollection(this);
});
```

How can I put a delay of say 2 seconds on each call to `setCBCollection(this)`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout):

```
$('input[name="f01"]:checked').each(function() {
    var element = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
        setCBCollection(element);
    }, 2000);
});
```

`setTimeout` schedules a function to be called *N* milliseconds later (roughly, these things are not precise).

Note that we grab `this` to a variable local to the event handler function, and then the function we pass into `setTimeout` is a closure over that variable (because otherwise, the meaning of `this` will get lost). More details:

- [*Closures are not complicated*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html)
- [*You must remember `this`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html)

---

**Off-topic**: There's a syntax error in your original, you're using `'` within a `'`-quoted string without escaping it. I changed it to `"` in my code above.